# Does Google Photos Backup keep album structure?

Tags: photos, google

Will the Google Photos Backup for OS X also back up the album structure from Photos.app? That is, will albums be available as collections on Google Photos after uploading?

Comment: This site works better with one question per "question", please feel free to ask your other question seperately.

Answer (score -1):

No album structure uploaded. raw upload of the pics.